# How to merge arrays from multiple json files with JQ?

Tags: jq

I have multiple JSON Files with the same structure , the list is the array.

```
$ jq 'keys' file_1.json
[
  "itemsPerPage",
  "links",
  "list",
  "startIndex"
]
```

the list field looks like this

file1.json

```
 "list" : [ {"id: 123, "fname":"SAM" }, {"id: 125, "fname":"JOE" } .....]
```

fileX.json

```
 "list" : [ {"id: 783, "fname":"Danny" }, {"id: 785, "fname":"Kingmo" } .....]
```

trying to generate an output as follows (Only List and Ignoring other fields which are itemsPerPage/links/startIndex)

```
 "list" : [ {"id: 123, "fname":"SAM" }, {"id: 125, "fname":"JOE" },  {"id: 783, "fname":"Danny" }, {"id: 785, "fname":"Kingmo" }]
```

what's the best way to read all those files in with jq and generate a single file with one list array that has all the objects from all the JSON files ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `inputs` function to get the content of all the JSON files together and append only the `.list` field together

```
jq -n '{ list: [ inputs.list ] | add }' file1.json file2.json
```